# Is there an AddUnique method similar to Addrange() for alist in C#

Tags: c#, collections, unique

I have a list in C#:

```
       var list = new List<Car>();
       list.AddRange(GetGreenCars());
       list.AddRange(GetBigCars());
       list.AddRange(GetSmallCars());
```

the issue is that some of the same cars get returned in different functions and I don't want them  in the list more than once.  Each car has a unique Name attribute.  Is there anyway I can have something like this above but will only add items if they are unique ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `List<T>` doesn't seem to be the appropriate collection here. You probably want an `ISet<T>` implementation such as [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) (or [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) if you need ordering).

To allow this, you will need to write an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation that defines equality between cars according to  the `Name` property. If this is the 'canonical' definition of car-equality, you can also consider directly building this definition into the `Car` type itself (`object.Equals`, `object.GetHashCode` and ideally implement `IEquatable<T>` too).

Answer (score 66):

One choice is to add them and remove the repeated ones:

```
var list = new List<Car>();
list.AddRange(GetGreenCars());
list.AddRange(GetBigCars());
list.AddRange(GetSmallCars());
list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I have duplicate objects within my collection.
Simply list = list.Distinct().ToList(); doesn't work.

Comment: Distinct will remove the duplicate objects. If your objects are not actually the same, you have to make your objects implement Equals() and GetHashCode()

Comment: This is the best way of doing things with a simple list, like a list of ints.

Comment: best simple idea

Answer (score 31):

Another option is to do something like:

```
public static void AddUnique<T>( this IList<T> self, IEnumerable<T> items )
{
    foreach(var item in items)
        if(!self.Contains(item))
            self.Add(item);
}


var list = new List<Car>();
list.AddUnique(GetGreenCars());
list.AddUnique(GetBigCars());
list.AddUnique(GetSmallCars());
```

Comment: this was so helpful to me.

Answer (score 15):

Given you override the `.Equals()` method for `Car` to determine one car object is the same as another car object, then the following should work w/o writing an extension method.

```cs
    var list = new List<Car>();
    list.AddRange(GetGreenCars()?.Except(list) ?? new List<Car>());
    list.AddRange(GetBigCars()?.Except(list) ?? new List<Car>());
    list.AddRange(GetSmallCars()?.Except(list) ?? new List<Car>());
```

Comment: Don't forget to override Equals() and GetHashCode() on Car or it won't actually match the object in Contains(). Otherwise, best answer.

Comment: You can also do something like this to compare a specific ID inside the object: vm.SearchResults.AddRange(searchResultsOr.Where(listOr => !searchResultsAnd.Select(listAnd => listAnd.PostId).Contains(listOr.PostId)));

Comment: You can shorten it a bit more: `GetGreenCars().Except(list)`

Answer (score 6):

Yet another option using Linq:

```
public static void AddUnique<T>(this IList<T> self, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
  self.AddRange(
    items.Where(x => self.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Name == x.Name) ==
    null).ToList());
}

var list = new List<Car>();
list.AddUnique(GetGreenCars());
list.AddUnique(GetBigCars());
list.AddUnique(GetSmallCars());
```

Answer (score 6):

I created an extension method that adds only unique values to anything implementing `ICollection<T>` (including a `List<T>`) from an `IEnumerable<T>`.  Unlike implementations that use `List<T>.Contains()`, this method allows you to specify a lambda expression that determines if two items are the same.

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds only items that do not exist in source.  May be very slow for large collections and some types of source.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type in the collection.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">Source collection</param>
/// <param name="predicate">Predicate to determine whether a new item is already in source.</param>
/// <param name="items">New items.</param>
public static void AddUniqueBy<T>(this ICollection<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        bool existsInSource = source.Where(s => predicate(s, item)).Any();
        if (!existsInSource) source.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
source.AddUniqueBy<Foo>((s, i) => s.Id == i.Id, items);
```

Comment: You don't need to daisychain Where and Any. You can just pass the func into the Any method.

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to compare one property (id in this case), this should work

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(GetGreenCars().Where(greencar => !list.Contains(greencar, car => car.id == greencar.id)));
list.AddRange(GetBigCars().Where(bigcar => !list.Contains(bigcar, car => car.id == bigcar.id)));
list.AddRange(GetSmallCars().Where(smallcar => !list.Contains(smallcar, car => car.id == smallcar.id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Linq-less option!**
A different option in case the programmer cannot, or don't wanna use Linq.

```
var list = new List<Car>();
list.AddRange(GetGreenCars().FindAll((x) => !list.Contains(x)));
list.AddRange(GetBigCars().FindAll((x) => !list.Contains(x)));
list.AddRange(GetSmallCars().FindAll((x) => !list.Contains(x)));
```

If the initial list is empty as in the example above, you can actually avoid using FindAll(...) on the first AddRange().

Comment: This will only work reliably on primitives. For composite types, you're going to have to be able to provide a comparison function.

Comment: @Jay yes, can be solved simply by implementing IEquatable on the custom type, so no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Get*Cars() return Lists of Car, another option could be:

```
var list = new List<Car>();
GetGreenCars().ForEach(c => { if (!list.Contains(c)) list.Add(c); });
GetBigCars().ForEach(c => { if (!list.Contains(c)) list.Add(c); });
GetSmallCars().ForEach(c => { if (!list.Contains(c)) list.Add(c); });
```