# Avoid Adding duplicate elements to a List C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, c#-4.0

```
string[] lines3 = new string[100];
List<string> lines2 = new List<string>();
lines3 = Regex.Split(s1, @"\s*,\s*");

if (!lines2.Contains(lines3.ToString()))
{
    lines2.AddRange(lines3.Distinct().ToArray());
}
```

I have checked all the spaces etc but i still get duplicate values in my lines2 `List`

I have to remove my duplicate values here itself

Comment: lines2 is the list of string sorry had made a small error while copying and pasting the code

Comment: there can be a space between two strings like=sbc bgp

Comment: Have you considered using a HashSet<String> instead of List<String> for this case, it will perform much better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an AddUnique method similar to Addrange() for alist in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652340/is-there-an-addunique-method-similar-to-addrange-for-alist-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your this check:

```
if (!lines2.Contains(lines3.ToString()))
```

is invalid. You are checking if your `lines2` contains `System.String[]` since `lines3.ToString()` will give you that. You need to check if item from `lines3`  exists in `lines2` or not.

You can iterate each item in `lines3` check if it exists in the `lines2` and then add it. Something like.

```
foreach (string str in lines3)
{
    if (!lines2.Contains(str))
        lines2.Add(str);
}
```

Or if your `lines2` is any empty list, then you can simply add the `lines3` distinct values to the list like:

```
lines2.AddRange(lines3.Distinct());
```

then your `lines2` will contain distinct values.

Answer (score 71):

You can use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) to get distinct items from lines3 which is not in lines2:

```
lines2.AddRange(lines3.Except(lines2));
```

If lines2 contains all items from lines3 then nothing will be added. BTW internally Except uses `Set<string>` to get distinct items from second sequence and to verify those items present in first sequence. So, it's pretty fast.

Comment: This is a good solution, and it's pretty fast. Until you have a couple of million of records. Then you'll have to consider using other methods like HasSet, Dictionary or similar instead. Just a heads up, from lessons learned the hard way ;)

Answer (score 43):

Use a `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List<string>`. It is prepared to perform a better performance because you don't need to provide checks for any items. The collection will manage it for you. That is the difference between a `list` and a `set`. For sample:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();

set.Add("a");
set.Add("a");
set.Add("b");
set.Add("c");
set.Add("b");
set.Add("c");
set.Add("a");
set.Add("d");
set.Add("e");
set.Add("e");

var total = set.Count;
```

Total is `5` and the values are `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`.

The implemention of `List<T>` does not give you nativelly. You can do it, but you have to provide this control. For sample, this `extension method`:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddItem<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
       if (!list.Contains(item))
       {
          list.Add(item);
       }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.AddItem(1);
list.AddItem(2);
list.AddItem(3);
list.AddItem(2);
list.AddItem(4);
list.AddItem(5);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `HashSet` is unordered, which means it doesn't retain the order the items were added. If he needs to retain a specific order, `HashSet` won't work.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want duplicates in a list, use a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).  That way it will be clear to anyone else reading your code what your intention was and you'll have less code to write since `HashSet` already handles what you are trying to do.

Comment: for those considering hashset pls be aware that you can't be guaranteed order

Answer (score 4):

You could use a simple `Union` + `Distinct`:

```
var lines = lines2.Union(lines3).Distinct();
```

That will add all the items from the second list into the first list, and then return all the unique strings in the combined list. Not likely to perform well with large lists, but it's simple.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your check would have worked, it would have either added all the items, or none at all. However, calling the `ToString` method on an array returns the name of the data type, not the contents of the array, and the `Contains` method can only look for a single item, not a collection of items anyway.

You have to check each string in the array:

```
string[] lines3;
List<string> lines2 = new List<string>();

lines3 = Regex.Split(s1, @"\s*,\s*");

foreach (string s in lines3) {
  if (!lines2.Contains(s)) {
    lines2.Add(s);
  }
}
```

However, if you start with an empty list, you can use the `Distinct` method to remove the duplicates, and you only need a single line of code:

```
List<string> lines2 = Regex.Split(s1, @"\s*,\s*").Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save distinct values into a collection you could try [HashSet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It will automatically remove the duplicate values and save your coding time. :)

Answer (score 1):

use `HashSet` it's better

take a look here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashset

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashSet` along with your `List`:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
HashSet<string> myHashSet = new HashSet<string>();

public void addToList(string s) {
    if (myHashSet.Add(s)) {
        myList.Add(s);
    }
}
```

`myHashSet.Add(s)` will return `true` if `s` is not exist in it.

Comment: Downside is that you can not use index on HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

not a good way but kind of quick fix,
take a bool to check if in whole list there is any duplicate entry.

```cs
bool containsKey;
string newKey;

public void addKey(string newKey)
{
    foreach (string key in MyKeys)
    {
        if (key == newKey)
        {
            containsKey = true;
        }
    }

    if (!containsKey)
    {
        MyKeys.add(newKey);
    }
    else
    {
        containsKey = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the hint from #Felipe Oriani, I made the extension which I would like to share here for good.

```
public static class CollectionExtension
{
    public static void AddUniqueItem<T>(this List<T> list, T item, bool throwException)
    {
        if (!list.Contains(item))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        else if(throwException)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Item already exists in the list");
        }
    }
    public static bool IsUnique<T>(this List<T> list, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        return list.Count == list.Distinct(comparer).Count();
    }
    public static bool IsUnique<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        return list.Count == list.Distinct().Count();
    }
}
```