# Check if value already exist in existing list before adding new data

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core

I have a table that store data from an uploaded excel sheet. Every time the user uploads a new list, it needs to check against the existing list if there's a duplicate value "A" before inserting a new row.
So far, this is what I have (as an example):

```
var originalData = await DataBase.ToListAsync();
List<Data> newData = new List<Data>();
/*... (getting data from file and add to newData list)...*/
/*** Below is where I have problem. What I try to achieve: 
1 - Compare "ValueA" value from the newly uploaded data to the existing data, if they're the same then don't add to the database. 
2 - Because the list that user upload may contains multiple rows with different datapoints and values but the same ValueA, it should only store one ValueA and ignore the rest (hence, the GroupBy) 
***/
var list = newData.Where(n => originalData.Any(o => n.ValueA == o.ValueA))
       .GroupBy(data => data.ValueA.ToLower())
       .Select(data => data.First());
foreach(Data d in list){
  DataBase.Add(d);
}
await DataBase.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When it uploads the files with multiple rows (with different data points) but the same value of `ValueA`, it adds the data with unique `ValueA` value (as expected). However, when I upload another file, it keeps adding even though it has duplicate value `ValueA`. The goal is to only add new data without the duplicate value of `ValueA`.

Comment: Isn't the predicate being given to `Where` getting all instances from `newData` that already exist in `originalData`? I think you need items where `originalData.Any(...)` returns `false`. Like... `newData.Where(n => !originalData.Any(o => o.ValueA == n.ValueA))`

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson I actually tried that at first but either way, it didn't make any difference and kept on adding new data even with same ValueA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid Adding duplicate elements to a List C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433332/avoid-adding-duplicate-elements-to-a-list-c-sharp)

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: @LeVic you can see here(https://dotnetfiddle.net/iXjUm8) that checking for `false` filters the list to items that exist in `newData` but not `originalData`. Is `ValueA` a `string`? You bring `ValueA` to lower case in the `GroupBy`, does the comparison `n.ValueA == o.ValueA` need to be case insensitive as well? Is it adding every item in `newData` whether it's a duplicate or not, or just the duplicates?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson you're correct! I messed up other conditions when I was testing it and should have put back the `!`. That works!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like ValueA is a string - you'd do better to check for string equality by using the String.Equals function `n.ValueA.Equals(o.ValueA)` instead of `n.ValueA == o.ValueA`. Additionally, your filter is specifically getting rows from newData that ***do*** have rows with the same ValueA already in originalData; you should use `!originalData.Any(...` instead. All together, it should look like the following:

```
var list = newData.Where(n => !originalData.Any(o => n.ValueA.Equals(o.ValueA)))
       .GroupBy(data => data.ValueA.ToLower())
       .Select(data => data.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the List.Contains method to check this.

```
foreach (var item in newData)
{
  if (originalData.Contains(item)
  {
     return;
  }
  else
  {
    originalData.Add(item );
  }
}
```